# R1a backbone SNP pack worth it?

Tags: dna, y-dna, familytreedna.com

I upgraded to Y-67 and my haplogroup stayed the same (R-M198).

Would it be worth it to purchase the R1a backbone SNP Pack to get a more specific haplogroup?

I currently can't afford Big-Y.

I currently don't know where my direct paternal line comes from. I was hoping a more specific haplogroup might give me an idea what part of the world they might originate from. I joined the R1a project. I'm predicted to be R-L664 and possibly S3477 specifically. Just wondering if the R1a backbone would be worth the $119.